# How can I share files between to routers connected by Ethernet

Tags: windows, networking, router, ethernet

I have two routers. Let's call them a and b for convenience.
Now my main router is router A it is connected to internet
The other router its on upper floor and its connected to the router A through ethernet cable now my desktop is connected to router a by Ethernet.
What I want is to send files from my desktop to the devices connected to router b
I apologize if this question has already been asked but I can't find a solution anywhere.

Comment: Sounds like you created two networks. Is this what you want/need? Does router B offer Wi-Fi coverage or something, or do you only need wired connectivity on the upper floor?

Comment: the best answer would be to put Router B in Bridge mode if possible, and make sure its DHCP server is disabled. that will make both routers participate on the same network, so all the hosts can see each other. if your Router B doesn't support bridge mode, then you can try putting your desktop in a DMZ (if supported).

Comment: You really need to advise your network setup in note detail, including why you deployed 2 routers (rather then a router and an access point), what IP addresses are used and what protocol you want to use to share files. There are multiple ways of doing this.

Comment: @DanielB Yeah the router B offer WIFI coverage but it takes internet from Router A through ethernet

Comment: @FrankThomas Okay I tried doin that but I still could not find DMZ in my routers settings or bridge mode!

Comment: @davidgo I deployed the second router to enhance the range of router 1 WIFI.As for protocols does not matter I'd use any.
I'd Just use the simplest way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so from your comments I take it you actually want a single network, but you accidentally created two (somewhat) isolated networks. To change this, router B needs to be reconfigured to work as an Wi-Fi Access Point.

1. Disconnect router B from router A.
2. Log in to router B’s configuration interface.
3. Change router B’s IP address so it is in router A’s subnet. Make sure you’re using an IP address that is not in router A’s DHCP range or otherwise in use.
4. (Update your DHCP lease so you can connect to the configuration interface again.)
5. Disable DHCP on router B.
6. Connect router B to router A: The cable needs to go into a *LAN* port on router B. The WAN port will remain unused.

You will then have a single network and all devices can talk to each other directly.

Comment: SNAP - we wrote roughly the sane answer at the sane time!

Answer (score 0):

From your question and comments you should change your router configuration. The problems you are having stem from having 2 routers in your network, where the second one is segmenting your network making communication less seemless.

The answer is to convert router B to an AP (access point) so that there is only 1 router - which means all the devices can talk to each other.

To turn router B into an AP -

1. Find an unused IP address on router A's LAN - one outside the range of DHCP addresses it uses. Get the netmask associated with this range. (On many routers 192.168.1.2 with a netmask of 255.255.255.0 will do).
2. Assign this IP address to the LAN interface on router B.
3. Disable DHCP on router B.
4. Move the WAN cable in router B to a LAN port (you won't use the WAN port any more)

You should now have everything on the same subnet, and machines on your LAN should be able to see each other. IP addresses for all dynamic IPs should now be assigned by router A.

You did not mention it, but if you have different SSIDs for WIFI for each router, if you program the same SSID, password and protocol into router A and B you should be able to roam seamlessly between the two routers.

Answer (score -1):

First You have to check IP Series on Both Router. Both Router Shouldn't use the Same IP Series. if your Main Router (A) is Using the Ip Series Example 192.168.0.1 and Another Router (B) is Using the IP Series 192.168.1.1 then You Have to Find Your Desktop (Router B Connected) ip Address. then Ping That IP Address from your (A Connected) Desktop using CMD. Example > CMD Command Promt > ping 192.168.1.35

if Ping Failed then You have to check your Router Routing Table

Please Note > Your Router B Should be connected through WAN Port to Router B. it must be Configured Obtain DHCP on Your Router B WAN Interface

Comment: But I want to get the DHCP through router A. Is it possible that way?